# Vue3 emit return event

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I create a simple select component to emit option value to parent component, like this

**Select component**

```
<template>
  <select
    @change="change($event)"
    class="shadow mb-3 appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
  >
    <option hidden selected>Select option</option>
    <option v-for="item in props.items" :value="item.value" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: "Select",
  props: {
    items: { type: Object, default: undefined },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const change = (event: any) => {
      emit("change", event.target.value);
    };
    return {
      props,
      change,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

In this **main component** y get value and set in variable

```
<Select @change.once="change" :items="types" />

setup(){
     function change(value: any) {
          type.value = value;
    }
return onChange
```

The problem is i receive

[image]

I need only the text, not the event. So, anybody saw what´s wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the outer `@change` event [falls through](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#v-on-listener-inheritance) to your select, and now it is triggered twice, once by the `<select>`s change event and again by the component's change event.

Keep that from happening by [declaring emitted events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events):

```
export default {
  name: "Select",
  emits: ['change'],
  ...
```

Alternatively, you could also just use the `change` event from `<select>` directly, tough I would do that explicitly then:

```html
<select
  v-bind="$attrs"
  ...
```

Comment: @elHombreSinNombre Looking a bit more into this, things are much simpler than what I initially claimed (sorry, hope I didn't send you down the wrong path)